# Review of String Field Theory

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, string-field-theory

Could anybody suggest the comprehensive review of [String Field Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_field_theory)? Original papers are lengthy and it would take quite a long time to read them all.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0102085

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An excellent review of Open String Field Theory may be found in *[Analytic methods in open string field theory](https://inspirehep.net/record/1226324?ln=en)* by Yuji Okawa. It develops the CFT formalism, presents the *Schnabl solution* and the associated solutions with detailed calculations.

The following detailed lecture notes by Washington Taylor and Barton Zwiebach are also of pedagogical in nature: "*D-Branes, Tachyons, and String Field Theory*": [arXiv:hep-th/0311017]. Carlo Maccaferri has a succinct review of the subject which gives a broad picture and clearly introduces the CFT formalism : *[Basics of Open String Field Theory](http://www.ulb.ac.be/sciences/ptm/pmif/Rencontres/ModaveII/Carlo.pdf)*

Another useful review may be the one by Ehud Fuchs and Michael Kroyter: "*Analytical Solutions of Open String Field Theory*" [arXiv:hep-th/0807.4722]. It discusses the CFT and the oscillator formalisms for covariant string field theory along with the Sen conjectures.

The Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) formalism - which is useful for constructing Closed String Field Theories - is discussed in the context of Open String Field Theory by Charles B. Thorn in this review article: "*String Field Theory*" [Phys.Rept. 175 (1989) 1-101]. The Berkovits formalism for superstring field theory is discussed in : "*Review of Open Superstring Field Theory*" by Nathan Berkovits - [arXiv:hep-th/0105230]